# (R) Automatically calculate optimized Arima(p, d , q) value

Tags: r, forecasting, java

I'm developing automatic forecast Software with JAVA & R.  The following steps are used in R to forecast next 18 values:

1. `trends <- scan("c:/data_for_R/trends.dat")`
2. `auto.arima(trends)` (cf. `arima(pdq)`)
3. `trendsarima <- arima(trends, order=c(2,1,3))`, note that `(2,1,3)` was found by the step #2)
4. `trendsforecasts <- forecast.Arima(trendsarima, h=18)`
5. `trendsforecasts`
6. `plot.forecast(trendsforecasts)`

All I want to know is, how do you integrate steps #2, #3 (preferably by a single command)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
trendsarima <- auto.arima(trends)
```